# pushd - handling multiple drives from cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, network-drive

I'm trying to figure out how to install some programs where the components reside on two different drives on a networked path. However whenever I use `pushd \\xyz\c$` I get a mapped drive which means I cannot use any knowledge of using for example `c:\install e:\mycomponents.dll`. Is there anyway that I can do this once I have used the pushd command?

How can I ensure that I keep the drives the same for example. I'm in the process of installing services. So it seems that when I install the service, I need to keep the path as the same as the actual location of the .exe which means that I'm running into issues.

Is there a way to simply use pushd but at the sametime not actually map drives? As when installing services, when I've been using `net use`, I've found that there is an issue with installing on drives which are mapped, as the service whilst can be installed doesn't find the actual .exe when it comes to starting up the service.

So to expand this, is there a way to solve this using `net use` or `pushd` or a combination that lets me install a service as such: `c:\windows\..\installutil  e:\mynode`?

So to clarify, I need to somehow be able to see both drives on the remote machine by their relative drives i.e. E:\ and C:\ - if I use a mapped drive letter then it means installing service is a pain because I cannot use the path.

**Issue 1:**

If I use pushd, then I cannot see both drive letters on the server.

```
net use i: %Machine1PathFRM%
pushd %Machine1PathZIP%
i:\installutil /username=ABC /password=abc %ZMN%
popd
```

**Issue 2:**

If I use `net use` then I whilst I can use this for say the install utils, when it comes to running the service, windows cant find the local file because it has performed some kind of file mapping process which is very very annoying indeed.

```
REM Install Processes Machine 1

REM net use e: %Machine1PathZIP%
REM net use i: %Machine1PathFRM%
REM i:\installutil /username=ABC /password=abc e:\%ZMN%
REM i:\installutil /username=ABC /password=abc e:\%ZPL%
```

Comment: Are You really using the single tasked DOS OS? Or You're just using a prompt window inside windows?

Comment: Your question is now a bit confusing. You should show the relevant part of your batch script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pushd //xyz/c$` will also change the current diretory to the mapped drive letter.

```
pushd //xyz/c$
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%cd%") do set "mapDrive=%%~dA"
%mapDrive%\install %mapDrive%:\mycomponents.dll
```

Comment: If he is using The Dos operating System, It won't work: because the extended for batch command is only available in NT version of windows. CMD.exe is far more powerful than the original command.com.

Comment: @user2284570 He can't use DOS, as he uses `PUSHD`

Comment: It is the case if he is using MS-DOS. But there are other DOS implementation. Most FreeDos apps batch interpreter have the Pushd command. But the syntax for the for command is still completely different than with cmd.exe. Also, he used the DOS tag (look at it's description). Today FreeDos seems more used than MS-DOS. Also, They where an improved interpreter for The MS-DOS environment: It was called 4DOS.

Comment: @user2284570 Pushd, c$, long filenames, a tag that lists `cmd`, it all points to Windows NT series cmd line and batch files.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. Here is my output: C:\>pushd \\ukmdng2\c$

Z:\>for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%cd%") do set "mapDrive=%%~dA"
%%A was unexpected at this time.

Comment: I'm on Win7 and logging onto remote Win Severs 2008 machines

Comment: It runs in a batch  File. From then cmd line you should change the double percents to single ones